# can I have a32 inline neon code excuted on iphone6(i.e. A64 machine)?

Tags: ios, arm, neon

I try to use a inline asm neon code in a iOS project as below:

```
 float modf_neon_sfp(float x, int *i)
 {
    #ifdef __MATH_NEON
    asm volatile (
    "vdup.f32       d0, r0                  \n\t"   //d0 = {x, x}   
    "vcvt.s32.f32   d1, d0                  \n\t"   //d1 = (int) d0; 
    "vcvt.f32.s32   d2, d1                  \n\t"   //d2 = (float) d1;
    "vsub.f32       d0, d0, d2              \n\t"   //d0 = d0 - d2; 
    "vstr.i32       s2, [r1]                \n\t"   //[r0] = d1[0] 
    "vmov.f32       r0, s0                  \n\t"   //r0 = d0[0];
    ::: "d0", "d1", "d2"
 );

#else
    return modf_c(x, i);
#endif
}
```

the code is A32 neon asm instruction. but it failed running on iphone6:
error:Unrecognized instruction mnemonic

is there a way to execute a32 asm neon code on a64 machine?

Comment: Similar to the way x86 does it, Aarch64 machines can execute code in 32 or 64-bit mode; the instructions and register model are different. The way around this problem is to write your code with intrinsics since they are compatible between 32 and 64-bit mode and will build properly for all environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

More detailed answer: The ARMv8-A architecture allows the execution state to change between AArch64 and AArch32 on exception boundaries, such as when moving in to or out of the kernel. While many ARMv8-A operating systems do support AArch32 and AArch64 binaries executing on the system, this tends to be done at a task granularity, rather than what you are asking for which is at a function (or even within a function!) granularity. Additionally, you would require tools to support compiling for and assembling both AArch32 and AArch64 code, these don't exist as the use case is unusual.

You'll want to either rewrite your Neon code using intrinsics, or port the assembler yourself.